# How to set the height and width of select tag option's drop down list

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, select

I have a select tag use on my jsp page. When the options are added for select then the dropdown list of option covers half of my page as well as width is also as per data and thus goes out of the page thus hides half of my data.

How can I set the height so when I click on the down arrow of the select it shows me first 5 options with a scroll for the others? And how to code so that its width can be adjusted?

Comment: Please post your code here

Answer (score 0):

He is correct, you could use a custom dropdown plugin like http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick or try adding size="5" to you  however this would remove the dropdown function and have it more like a list.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
overflow-y:auto;
```

hope it helped